# Design pattern Technique

Tags: design-patterns

[image]

Hello All,

My question is actually related to design pattern kind off stuff.

As in image, I have 3 layers, UI layer, Business Logic layer and DB layer,

**My Question :** I want to Design Business Logic layer such that Any UI tech can access,
Ex: UI1-Web is a Web Based UI, UI2-Windows is a Windows based UI, And similarly anything else.
Whatever the UI technology is, it should be able to consume the Business object, and shouldn't cause any changes in Business logic layer.

**How exactly to do this, what programming language needs be used, what technology needs to be used?**

Pls help me with as much as detail as possible.

Comment: This is classic MVC pattern that's executed in every language there is.  Every language I know supports it.  The current fashion would say REST web services.

Comment: I want to have one language for all, currently user needs only windows application, In future user will say web based, How to incorporate this?

Comment: Web and desktop will always be two different things.  Your best bet is to use HTTP to communicate between all clients and the server.  The server will stay the same, but the UI can change at will.

Comment: Single language for applications?  It's a polyglot world.  Web demands HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, etc.  If you use HTTP and REST services, the back end can be written in any language you wish without affecting the client.

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern best suited to your requirements is the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).